# C++ for loop multiple condition inconsistency

Tags: c++, for-loop

Code in question :

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a[10] = {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1};

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) if (a[i] == 1) cout<<i<<" ";

    cout<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10 && a[i] == 1; ++i) cout<<i<<" ";

    cout<<endl;

}
```

Output:

```
1 3 5 6 9
// and an empty line
```

If my understanding of condition evaluation is correct, then both the outputs should be the same. As the condition `a[i] == 1` is checked each time, `i` is incremented. So, why is this happening?

I have tested this with g++ and an online ide called ideone [link to code](https://www.ideone.com/iehH82).

I believe that I am missing something very basic here and it is a very dumb issue, so please forgive me for asking this in advance.

Comment: As soon as the condition is false, it will **terminate the `for` loop**.

Comment: The condition is checked before executing the body of the loop.  So, starting with `i = 0` the condition `i < 10 && a[i] ==1` is evaluated.  `a[0]` is `0`, so the condition is false, and the loop body is never executed.

Comment: Oh man, turns out I _am_ an idiot after all :3

Answer (score 1):

the condition loop finish in i = 0 because a[0]=0 . your condition to continue is a[i]=1. therefore it finish in first case

Answer (score 1):

The condition in the `for` loop is evaluated before **each** iteration, and if it yields `false`, the loop is exited.

In the first case the condition is `i < 10` and this becomes `false` only **after** `i` reaches 10, so the condition in the `if` is evaluated 10 times and you get the output `1 3 5 6 9`.

In the second case the condition is `i < 10 && a[i] == 1` which becomes `false` on the very first iteration when `i` is 0 as `a[0]` is 0. The `for` loop is then terminated and the condition in the `if` statement is never evaluated and so you do not get any output.

Answer (score 0):

No. The results are not the same. In the first one, the **for** loop scrolls over 0 to 9 and each time the inner **if** checks whether the corresponding index of **a** is equal to 1 or not. So the performance of the first one is clear. The second one acts quite different. The second **for**  holds as long as the condition holds (while it doesn't even hold at the beginning since **a[0]=0**).

A better example is:

```
int x[]={1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1};
```

the first loop prints out 0 1 2 8 9 and the second one's output is 0 1 2.